# Передача нескольких JSON массивов ajax jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

У меня есть некий `json` файл: `[{1},{2}] [{3},{4}]`.
В этом файле есть 2 массива.
Как можно обратиться только к массиву `[{3},{4}]` посредством ajax, jquery?

```js
$.ajax({
  type: 'post',
  url: 'Servlet',
  data: data,
  response: 'json',
  success: function(response) {
    // как здесь получить доступ ко второму массиву?
  },
  error: function(xhr, status, err) {
    alert('Ошибка');
  }
});
```

Comment: вопрос вообще не понятный, из ващего куска кода никак не ясно кто обращаеться к json файлу? `php` или `javascript`. Надо сделать поправку в вопросе и нормально обяснить что у вас есть и что нужно.

Comment: Вы получите все данные из файла в переменной data в success(). Можете обращаться к ним как угодно. Или вы хотите получить только часть данных? Если так то это невозможно.

Comment: Только часть данных т.е то что в первых []

Comment: Тогда вам нужна либо динамическая генерация данных на серверной стороне, либо данные разделить на два json файла и обращаться к каждому.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Такой файл не является корректным json файлом. Согласно стандарту json на верхнем уровне должен находиться *ровно один* массив/объект/число/строка.

Возможное решение: убрать `response: json`. Тогда вы будете получать не распарсенный json объект, а строку. Вам нужно будет самостоятельно разбить эту строку на две подстроки, каждая из которых представляет json массив. Затем преобразовать каждую строку в массив с помощью метода [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

Разбить строку на две части можно, например, найдя в ней подстроку `] [`:

```js
let string = '[1,2] [3,4]';
let index = string.indexOf('] [');
let array1 = JSON.parse(string.substr(0, index + 1));
let array2 = JSON.parse(string.substr(index + 2));
console.log(array1);
console.log(array2);
```

В большинстве случаев это будет работать.